# How use object after release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

foo declaration in h. file

I do [foo release] operation

Next i need use foo second time. How?

Comment: Why would you release it if you know you'll be needing it again?

Comment: Umm, don't `release` until you are done with it.

Comment: Unless he want's a different `foo` in there

Comment: I suggest you obtain a book on Objective-C and/or Cocoa / Cocoa Touch and learn from the beginning.

Comment: I know that i need.  I find that i can do foo=nil;   But next Q - why i can't   foo= [[boo alloc] init];   It doesn't work

Comment: That should work. If you're sure that it doesn't, post your code so we can show you what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot reuse an object after it has been deallocated.

You must simply not release it until after the second operation is complete.

Answer (score 5):

As stated before, you cannot use objects after they have been deallocated. Deallocation occurs when their `retainCount` goes to zero. If, for some reason, you cannot remove that `[foo release]` call, you must call `[foo retain]` beforehand. You can also try to call `[foo autorelease]` instead of `[foo release]`, if your second usage is shortly after.

There is a very good walkthrough for memory management in Objective-C here: [Stanford's cs193p Lecture 4](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%204.pdf)